# 0 I am trying to run a project by Tomcat in Eclipse, but when I click on that, it shows an error:

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

[image]

I downloaded Tomcat 9 for my windows, and I installed. 
And running in Eclipse However, I can't any project because of error shown in the above image.

Comment: Please also include the error text here, so it can be found by searches and if the image link breaks in the future.

Comment: The image shows only a very generic error message, even without the details offered. On the right side, you see the unimportant part of a stacktrace. Include the full information (details and stackgrace) in the question - without it, it's impossible to see what happens.